# Elementary geometry problem - finding one side of rectangle given two parameters

Tags: geometry

[image]

This is an elementary problem I have been surprisingly finding hard to solve only by using elementary level math (no trigonometry).

The only given parameters are:

**1** is the distance from the intersection (between the diagonal and bisector of $\angle D$) to the side $AB$

**8** is the distance from the intersection (between the diagonal and the bisector) to the side $CB$.

I need to find the length of the side $AB$. How would you solve it, and what's more important (to me) is how would you explain it to a kid who is just starting to learn geometry?

Comment: To be clear, the "bisection" is an angle bisector of the corner right?

Comment: @79037662 Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear enough!

Comment: By "bissection" you mean the "diagonal" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie no, the bisection is the bisector line which halves the angle in the upper-left corner

Comment: Therefore 1) You should replace the word "bisection" (intended to designate an action) by the term "angle bisector" (a noun)  2) Maybe modify your figure in order that the two angles in $D$ look close to be 45°-45°, and not 30°-60°...

Comment: Why you draw the bisector as perpendicular to diagonal - it is misleading you!

Comment: Why you show the bisector as perpendicular?

Comment: There is no definite solution to AB! Any square add at a corner of 1X8 rectangle will do.

Comment: The length of the side $AB$ is equal to $8+2\sqrt{2}$ (=10.82842). I can explain the method of solving to you. But explaining it to a kid, whose exact educational background is not known to me, is not going to go well. One needs to know the Theorem 85 (Euclid VI. 2.) and solution to the quadratic equation. If you promise to take over the educating the kid, I will post my answer.

Comment: @YNK Please do! It's become burdensome to me also so I want to know the answer myself!

Comment: I just "rectified" the figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the picture below, the red and blue right triangles are similar (because of parallel sides) and the purple triangle $\triangle DOZ$ is an isosceles right triangle (because $DO$ is an angle bisector, making $\angle ODZ = 45^\circ$).

[image]

Let $AX = x$. Then $DZ = x$ as well; therefore $OZ = x$, because $\triangle DOZ$ is isosceles; therefore $YC = x$.

Since the red and blue triangles are similar, their legs are in the same ratio: $AX : XO = OY : YC$, or $x : 1 = 8 : x$. Rearranging, we get $x^2 = 8$, or $x=\sqrt 8$.

Finally, $AB = AX + XB = AX + OY = \sqrt8 + 8$.

Comment: [+1] Nice proof !

Comment: @JeanMarie No - it was not a nice proof! I just realized that there is a much shorter solution, and I have edited. *This* is the nice proof.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: With your edit, I no longer need to post my solution. Thanks? :)